# Examine convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a \cdot |\sin(x)| ^b}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Examine convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a \cdot |\sin(x)| ^b}dx$ for $a, b > 0$. There are 2 problems. $|\sin(x)|^b = 0$ for $x = k \pi$ and $x^a = 0$ for $x = 0$. We can write $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a \cdot |\sin(x)| ^b}dx = \int_0^{1} \frac{1}{x^a \cdot |\sin(x)| ^b}dx + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^a \cdot |\sin(x)| ^b}dx$ but what to do next?

Comment: Your integral diverges.  Are you sure that you aren't looking for the integral from 1 to infinity?

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Ok then.  It's easy.  The integral diverges.  It doesn't exist.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows Can you post answer with a proof, please?

Comment: Near $0$ the integrand looks like $1/x^{a+b}. $ That will give divergence on  $(0,1)$ unless  $a+b <1. $ But $a<1$ gives divergence on $[1,\infty).$  So there is no hope for convergence for this integral.

Answer (score 1):

To even have a chance at convergence at $\infty$, you need $a > 1$. However, then near $x = 0$, we have $x^a \lvert \sin(x) \rvert^b \approx x^{a+b}$ and since $a+b > 1$, we will have divergence near $x=0$. Thus the integral diverges for all $a,b > 0$.

Comment: You mean near $x = 0$ we have $x^a|\sin(x)|^b < x^{a+b}$? Why it means that we will have divergence?

Comment: Why?  This answer needs more explanation.

Comment: The answer provides all the elements for any reasonable doubt.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \frac{1}{xsin(x)}$.  $f$ is strictly positive.  Let's start by looking at some interval on which $f(x)$ is discontinuous.  How about $[3,\pi]$.  To show that $f$ diverges we need to find a lower bound and show that it diverges.  Because $x$ is bounded we can pick $g(x) = \frac{1}{4sin(x)}$.  If you integrate that function you will find that it goes off to infinity.  Therefore the integral diverges.

We now have to show that if there is any open interval on which the integral diverges the entire integral diverges.  Luckily this is easy.  As we have already established $f$ is strictly positive therefore the integral of $f$ is strictly positive.

If you want to show that this is true for all $a, b$ just recognize you can choose an interval in which $x$ is bounded and that there is some interval that contains a discontinuity and $csc(x)^n$ diverges for all $n$.

I hope this helps.  I really like this problem.  I'm going to get a class to do this tomorrow for extra credit or something tomorrow.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if $b=0$ then it's different because $sin(x)^b=1$ so you just have a basic integral that is integrable everywhere.

Comment: Could you say what is wrong with RRL's answer?

Comment: Their answer isn't wrong so much as incomplete.  I don't think anything they said was wrong but they just didn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{-1} \sin x = 1$ and on $[0,1]$ we have $\sin 1 \leqslant x^{-1} \sin x \leqslant 1.$

Hence, with $a,b > 0$,

$$(\sin 1)^b x^{a+b} \leqslant x^a |\sin x|^b = x^{a+b}|x^{-1} \sin x |^b \leqslant x^{a+b},$$

and

$$\frac{1}{x^{a+b}} \leqslant \frac{1}{x^a |\sin x|^b} \leqslant \frac{(\sin 1)^{-b}}{x^{a+b} }.$$

By the comparison test, the integral over $[0,1]$ converges if $a+b < 1$ and diverges if $a+b \geqslant 1.$

You can show the integral over $[1, \infty)$ diverges if $a \leqslant 1$ by comparing with a divergent $p$-series, using

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^a |\sin x|^b} \, dx \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{2k \pi + \pi/4}^{2k \pi + \pi/2} \frac{1}{x^a |\sin x|^b} \, dx. $$

Since $0 < 1/\sqrt{2}\leqslant \sin x  \leqslant 1$ on $[2k\pi + \pi/4, 2k \pi + \pi/2],$ we have

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^a |\sin x|^b} \, dx \geqslant \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2\pi)^a(k + 1/4)^a } \geqslant \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4\pi)^ak^a } . $$

Comment: You didn't really answer the question for $x>1$.  You should add something about it's divergence for any $a, b$.